# Extracting data from Filemaker application

Tags: reverse-engineering, filemaker, data-extraction

I have an end user version of an application written in FileMaker 10 (FML10.dll) and I need the data behind the software. Anyone knows a way to extract the data?
Looks like the USR file containts the data, but I don't know how to open it. Is there a way to query it throught c#?

```
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\ASAS 2013-01
   Asas 2013-01.exe
   Asas 2013-01.USR
   DBConverter.dll
   DBEngine.dll
   DOMSupport.dll
   FML10.dll
   FMLayout.dll
   FMOLE.dll
   FMPA Acknowledgements.pdf
   FMRSRC.dll
   FMScript.dll
   FMUserModel.dll
   FMWrapper.dll
   GdiPlus.dll
   HBAM.dll
   libeay32.dll
   MFCX.dll
   NSViews.dll
   OmniDynamic4.dll
   OmniORB4.dll
   OmniThread.dll
   PlatformSupport.dll
   ProofReader.dll
   ssleay32.dll
   Support.dll
   uninstal.exe
   uninstal.ini
   XalanDOM.dll
   XalanExtensions.dll
   XalanSourceTree.dll
   XalanTransformer.dll
   XCore.dll
   XDraw.dll
   Xerces.dll
   XercesParserLiaison.dll
   XFC.dll
   XGrfx.dll
   XMLEngine.dll
   XMLSupport.dll
   XPath.dll
   XSLT.dll
   XText.dll
Extensions
   Langs and etc..
Microsoft.VC80.CRT
       ...
Microsoft.VC80.MFC
       ...
Microsoft.VC80.MFCLOC
        ...
```

Comment: Don't know about C#, but there should be odbc drivers for Filemaker...

Comment: @appl3r: Why didn't you post your question on [reverseengineering.stackexchange.com](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) ? Should be more suitable there.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know there is a forum for that. Should I delete this one and post it there?

Answer (score 0):

The `Asas 2013-01.USR` file contains the data AND the logic. However, the file is encrypted. You can open the file using either `Asas 2013-01.exe` (double-clicking `Asas 2013-01.exe` should do this automatically) or Filemaker application. What you can do once the file is opened depends on the privileges your login account has.

Comment: When I start the program (Asas 2013-01.exe) I don't need to input any credentials, it displays the data right away. Do you think I would need a password when opening it with Filemaker? (I don't have the software right now)

Comment: @appl3r No. The credentials requirements are in the .USR file. If you're not asked to enter them, then the file is set to log in automatically, using account/password stored in the file's preferences. In any case, if this default account allows you to export the data, then you should be all set.

Comment: with the default account i can't, is there any way to open it so I can debug and export?

Comment: @appl3r Are you sure this is a problem of privileges? What exactly is stopping you?

Comment: There is no menu at all, only the GUI. Doesn't matter If I open it with ASAS 2013-01.exe or FileMaker.

Comment: @appl3r Do you mean it opens in kiosk mode: full screen, without any toolbars or menus?

Comment: Windowed, but no toolbars or menus. Same with FileMaker 12 Pro (it converted the Filemaker 7.5 database to fmp12)

Comment: @appl3r I suggest you give it up. If you can browse the data you need, then you can get it out by copying and pasting (if that's enabled - otherwise you'd need to use screenshots and OCR, or hire a typist). You can probably mechanize the process by using OS-level scripting. Or (preferably, IMHO) approach the person who has access privileges to the file.

Comment: Right now, I made a macro, which is browsing through all the data (not everything is browsable this way) and printing it to pdf. But it is slow, not really trustable, and later I need to extract the text and images from the pdf files.

Comment: @appl3r Count your blessings.